# Need .last() functionality for categories – .last() will be deprecated going forward

Tags: categories, craft3

I have a matrix block that calls a category channel. The categories are nested three levels "deep" at times. I want to select first, second or third level links as needed.

When I use .last(), I can get the full url path to return. When I use .nth(n), I have to specify a value, which automatically limits the link path to that level of "deepness".

What can I do to **get the .last() functionality, without using .last()?**

Note: *.last() will be deprecated going forward in Craft 3 and beyond*.

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not going to update your current project to Craft 3 (which will break nearly all your templates and all plugins anyway) you don't need to bother about that message. This is only for Craft 3 and not for Craft 2.

Otherwise looking in the [docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#element-queries) might be a good idea. You can do

```
{% set query = craft.entries().section('news') %}
{% set total = query.count() %}
{% set last = query.nth(total - 1) %}
```

or

```
{% set oldest = craft.entries()
    .section('news')
    .inReverse()
    .one() 
%}
```

Comment: So I am working in Craft 3 already and that link to the docs is very useful. I implemented `nth(query.count() - 1)` and it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: That docs link is now dead. This [one](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/341b0d451507944dea8ba4bbefadce5a7298315d/en/changes-in-craft-3.md#last)  might be comparable. It also suggests: In most cases you can replace calls to `.last()` with `.inReverse().one()`

Comment: @kr37 your link is now dead as well. Any updated?

Comment: At this point, I'd say go to [https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/) and search for inReverse